# Найти площадь по координатам

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия

Треугольник задается координатами своих вершин на плоскости: A(x1, y1), В (х2,, у2),
С (х3, y3). Найти площадь треугольника ABC.
не понимаю как площадь ввести. формулу нашел в инете S = 0,5*(x1-x3)(y2-y3);-(x2- x3)(y1-y3)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: формула Герона не так записывается...

Comment: подскажешь как записать формулу герона в код и что мне нужно дописать в проге?

Comment: Это не формула Герона вообще. И формула Герона тут совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: Тебя не смущает точка с запятой в середине формулы?

Answer (score 1):

Площадь треугольника навскидку можно найти двумя методами.

1. Формула Герона: `sqrt(p(p-a)p-b)(p-c))`, где `a`,`b`,`c` - длины сторон, `p` - полупериметр.
2. Как половину длины векторного произведения двух сторон. Формулу векторного произведения можно подсмотреть в Интернете - впрочем, вы ее и подсмотрели :)

Вот, чтоб убедиться в их равнозначности -

```
double x0 = 1, y0 = 3, x1 = 5, y1 = 7, x2 = -3, y2 = -6;

double a = sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
double b = sqrt((x2-x0)*(x2-x0) + (y2-y0)*(y2-y0));
double c = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
double p = (a+b+c)/2;
cout << "S = " << sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)) << endl;

cout << "S = " << fabs((x1-x0)*(y2-y0)-(x2-x0)*(y1-y0))/2 << endl;
cout << "S = " << fabs((x1-x2)*(y0-y2)-(x0-x2)*(y1-y2))/2 << endl;
```

Две последних - для разных пар сторон.